# iOS Custom Font displaced

Tags: ios, ipad, uifont

For a project I bought a `OTF` font and included it into my project (with adding to plist file etc). It works and I can set the font on my buttons, but the label is displaced then. I added a screenshot so you can see my issue. Anyone an idea what the problem can be?

system: iPad 3 with  iOS 6.0 beta, but same problem on iOS 5.1.1

[image]

EDIT:

I found a post about the problem.

http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, now I got it :) Just look at the blogpost I linked in my question.

> http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

summary:

- Download the Apple Font Tool Suite
- Terminal: ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d font.ttf
- XML file created in the directory
- Open XML with Text Editor and adjust the settings of ascender, descender
- Terminal:ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f font.ttf
- Add custom font to your projekt(dont forget plist item)

Comment: Thanks for the summary, as the link is offline now.

Comment: @lkraider should be back up - I just informed andy yardley on twitter about it :x

Answer (score 0):

you can re-align the `UIButton`'s text place with:

```
[_button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 10.f, 0.f)]; // e.g.
```

Comment: I know, but for me thats not really a solution :) But I appreciate your comment, but I had to give my own answer the mark for the accepted answer, because I think that is the real way to go.