# Fixing custom font vertical position. Apple Font Tool Suite not available anymore?

Tags: ios, fonts, vertical-alignment, custom-font

I followed the link in [Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/), and I'm redirected to the downloads site. There I can´t find the `Apple Font Suite Tool` package, has it been renamed? Or it doesn't longer exist?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I'm using custom fonts in my iOS app, and it seems that they add a vertical offset below the texts, something like the problem described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683280/ios-custom-font-displaced), at least regarding button titles. The solution provided leads to using `Apple Font Suite Tool` to fix this. Is there an alternative way? Thanks

Comment: If you have a programming question, it's far better to just ask that question instead of asking about links on a website on stackoverflow, which has nothing to do with those links. Your first question(s) are questions for google, not Stackoverflow. Your edit suggests you have a real question. Post that instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You're right, but I asked the second in case the tool I'm looking for is actually no longer available

Comment: the "edit" question, however, has no details or code though, so make that main question, explain what you're doing, what you've tried, and what you think you want to do but can't because the tool you need seems to have vanished, and now we have an excellent question for people in the future to find as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is called `OS X Font Tools` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following commands

ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d font.ttf

this generates an xml file that you tweak the params

ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f font.ttf

This info is from this post:http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

It worked for me